# Resources defined in UserControl.Resources can not see elements defined in MergedDictionaries set from code

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

`DefaultStyle`s contains a `DefaultStyle` for all `TextBox`es:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new DefaultStyles());
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then the Xaml, I inherit the style and add a little more:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green "/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This throws a `StackOverFlowException` as my `DefaultStyle` is not found, and so it trys to self reference.

**Why can't the Style see the default styles in the merged dictionary?**

Answer (score 0):

It can't see it because it's essentially replacing it. The `InitializeComponent` method call will replace the dictionary you refer to in your ctor with the dictionary you define in your XAML.

Basically, you're doing it wrong. Why can't you just do this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: This is what I thought was happening, but it isn't. The dictionaries merged in code are available to the rest of the control and dynamically to resources of UserControl, regardless of whether a Resources is defined in XAML.

Comment: we have a composite app, each module is independently styled. A custom UserControl base class which injects common styles is the only way we can think of to get an App.xaml equivalent of global module styles. Don't want to have to link them into every control